# Glimpse History tab not showing other clients

Tags: glimpse

I recently installed Glimpse and **love** it.  In the video http://getglimpse.com/ it says the history tab is for inspecting requests from other clients hitting the site (when they have Glimpse turned on).  When I try it out, I'm only seeing my current client with a count of 25.  I've tried logging in from other browsers (on the same machine) with the same username and with different usernames, still only see one entry in the list.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is Glimpse being used in your situation? Are you running it on localhost or on a server somewhere? Is that sever part of a web farm?

Comment: All on localhost - ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Seems like you are using it properly. Try resetting your webserver. Do you have the same experience when there have been less than 25 total requests?

Comment: Resetting the web server (iisreset) sets the count back to 1.  Hitting it from other browsers just increments the count for the one client.  Even if I hit from a different machine with a different username.

Comment: Once the count gets to 25, it stops going up.

Comment: OK... closing all the browsers, doing an iisreset, and then hitting the site again with glimpse turned on, it's now working.  Although the IE client is showing-up as my AD username.  Not sure which (or all) of them was needed, but it appears to be working now.  Is 25 the limit for requests it will track?  Any upper limit on the number of clients it'll track?

Comment: Yes, 25 is the limit for requests that Glimpse will track. No limit on the number of clients. You can override the client name by clicking the "Set Session Name" button on Glimpse.axd

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @BZink yes I got this to work by: closing all the browsers, doing an iisreset, and then hitting the site again with glimpse turned on

Comment: Thanks. I'll try restarting IIS.